# Use of past simple or past perfect in this sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

However, after she ____ (teach) English for a few years, she ______ (decide) to try her hand at her real passion- writing.

I'm not sure how i'm supposed to implement the past perfect and or the past simple in this sentence.

Comment: Both are possible with the past perfect putting an emphasis implying that she quit teaching and switched to writing while the simple past would imply that she might continue teaching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, after she **had taught** English for a few years, she **decided** to try her hand at her real passion - writing.

It is probably also grammatically correct to use the past-simple "... she taught English ..." but the past-perfect is more appropriate.

Past-perfect is used when the action was completed before some other past action.  Her teaching English had occured before her deciding to try writing.  Even if she was still teaching the act of teaching *for a few years* was completed.